# How to label CTAs in a mobile form?

Tags: forms, mobile, mobile-application, labels, call-to-action

I am currently working on a mobile flow for sending money (bitcoins to be specific).

I have found apps that label their CTA with the action on the upcoming screen, instead of referencing the current screen.

I realized that my flow works with both approaches, so I am wondering:  Between referencing the current screen/action or referencing the following screen, is there a best way to label CTAs? What should I be considering here?

Attaching the flow with the two different approaches.

[image: Referencing current screen]
[image: Referencing upcoming screen]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Material Design Guide](https://material.io/design/components/buttons.html#anatomy) has a good definition of a text button:

> Text buttons and contained buttons use text labels, which **describe the action** that will occur if a user taps a button. If a text label is not used, an icon should be present to signify what the button does.

So, according to this, the current action CTA seems a better choice. The user will know what action he will accomplish by clicking the button.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Aline's answer — to add something to her answer, the button label should describe what will happen when I click the button with **the current state information**.

Showing what the next step will be looks more like a "link" behaviour, instead of a button behaviour.